# Radius of convergence of $ \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(\frac{5^n + (-1)^n}{n^3}\right)(x-2)^n $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to find the radius of convergence for the following series:

\begin{align} 
  \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(\frac{5^n + (-1)^n}{n^3}\right)(x-2)^n
\end{align}

My steps are as follows:

By ratio test,

\begin{align}
  \left(\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^3}\right)\left(\frac{n^3}{5^n + (-1)^n}\right)|x-2|
  =\left(\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^n + (-1)^n}\right)\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^3|x-2|
\end{align}

As $ n $ goes to $ \infty $,

\begin{align}
  \left(\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^n + (-1)^n}\right) \to \infty \text{ ($ 5^{n+1} $ is the dominant term)}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^3 \to 1 \text{ (by l'hopital's rule) }
\end{align}

Hence, the expression becomes:

\begin{align}
  1 \cdot \infty \cdot |x-2| = \infty \cdot |x-2| \text{ as $ n $ goes to $ \infty $ }
\end{align}

Thus series only converges at $x=2$. This means that the radius of convergence is  $0$. Somehow, the correct answer is $ \frac{1}{5} $. Could someone please advise me on why my method is wrong?

Comment: You wrote that $\left(\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^n + (-1)^n}\right) \to \infty$ but $\left(\frac{5^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^n + (-1)^n}\right) \to 5$

Comment: @Astyx Why is that so? Isn't $ 5^{n+1} $ the dominant term?

Comment: Yes $5^{n+1}$ is the dominant term of the numerator, but $5^n$ is the dominant term of the denominator and thus the term converges to $5 = {5^{n+1}\over5^n}$

Comment: @Astyx Isn't $ 5^{n+1} > 5^{n} $ for $ n \to \infty $? So the expression should be $ \infty $ ?

Comment: No, this only works for finite sums. for products (resp quotients) you can take the product (resp quotient) of the dominant term of each term.

Comment: @Astyx By finite sums, you mean single expressions without division/multiplication?

Comment: I mean that for instance $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^k$ is not equivalent to $n^n$ (but to $n^{n+1}$)

Comment: @Astyx Ok I get it. You mean that if n goes to finite value then I can substitute in that finite value into the expression like I did in my question?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean here, could you please rephrase it ?

Comment: @Astyx E.g. $ n \to 10 $ then I can evaluate $ \frac{5^{n + 1} + (-1)^{n+1}}{5^{n} + (-1)^{n}} $ as $ \frac{5^{10 + 1} + (-1)^{10 + 1}}{5^{10 } + (-1)^{10}} $?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48035/discussion-between-astyx-and-lancehaoh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that

\begin{align} 
  \left(\frac{5^n + (-1)^n}{n^3}\right)(x-2)^n \sim {5^n(x-2)^n\over n^3}
\end{align}

Thus your series converges iff $|5(x-2)| \le 1$, ie $x\in[{9\over5}, {11\over5}]$, ie $|x-2|\le{1\over5}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the ratio test and using

$5^n+(-1)^n\sim 5^n (n\to+\infty)$,

we find

$5|x-2|$ as a limit.

$|x-2|<\frac{1}{5} \implies$ the series converge.

$|x-2|>\frac{1}{5} \implies$ it diverges.

thus, arround $x=2$, the radius convergence is $$R=\frac{1}{5}.$$

Comment: I don't understand how you managed to get $ 5|x-2| $. I performed the ratio test but got a different answer as I wrote in my question.